# 連想配列のkey（Keyの順番は固定）とvalueの組み合わせをシャッフル方法

Tags: php

連想配列のkey(Keyの順番は固定)とvalueの組み合わせをシャッフルする方法はありませんか？
`array_rand()`を使ったのですが、何も変わらず
`shuffle`を使うと数字の配列になってしまいます。
どうすれば良いかわかりません。

```
array (
  'Philippines' => 'banana',
  'Japan' => 'rice',
  'France' => 'bread',
  'India' => 'curry',
)
```

これをランダムにシャッフルして、
以下のようにしたいのですが、

```
array (
  'Philippines' => 'rice',
  'Japan' => 'curry',
  'France' => 'banana',
  'India' => 'bread',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

keyとvalueを取り出して、valueのみシャッフルする方法です。

```
<?php
$ar = array (
  'Philippines' => 'banana',
  'Japan' => 'rice',
  'France' => 'bread',
  'India' => 'curry',
);

$keys = array_keys($ar);
$values = array_values($ar);
shuffle($values);

for($i = 0; $i < count($ar); $i++) {
    $ar[$keys[$i]] = $values[$i];
}

print_r($ar);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

shuffle を使用せずに array_rand を使ってやってみました。

```
<?php

$ar = array (
  'Philippines' => 'banana',
  'Japan' => 'rice',
  'France' => 'bread',
  'India' => 'curry',
) ;

$values = array_values($ar) ;

foreach($ar as $key => $dummy){
    $x = array_rand($values,1) ;
    $ar[$key] = $values[$x] ;
    unset($values[$x]) ;
}

print_r($ar) ;
```

同じ物が二度使用されないように使い終わったら unset するのがミソです。